# Can you buy multiple shares at once?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

If you have a lot of money and you want to buy all the ammo that you can you can just press square(ps3) when buying ammo, so you will buy all the ammo that you can carry for that gun.
But is there any way to do something like that with shares? If i have 2 millions and i want to spend it all in shares is there an faster way to do it other than just keep pressing X?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've searched high and low for a faster way, as I repeatedly invested in the stock market post-game to build up my characters net worth into the billions.

However, the only way I'm aware of is to hold the button down while your cursor is over the "+" icon.  As you hold, the counter will accelerate.  It still takes a good 20-30 seconds to max out your shares bought if you're buying a cheap stock and you have a ton of cash, though.

Comment: you can hold it? i didn't know that, at least it's a bit faster while holding it

Comment: @LuccaDornelles, yes, you can hold it down on the plus icon, and it is super fast compared to tapping it.  Still slow, but man, I would not want to buy individual shares at the billions I was investing at a time :)

Comment: Thanks. Every time I would hold the button down, I'd let go evidently just before it started going real fast. I'd see it not doing anything, and let go.